# wordpress custom_header does not save any changes

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i'm building a wp theme from scratch, im using xampp as a local server and wordpress 4.3, the problem comes when i click on "customize" and change the header image, then i click "save and publish" but i still have the last image i had and the changes i made from the customize menu dont take effect some times. here is the current code i have:

functions.php

```
register_default_headers( array(
'logo1' => array(
    'url'           => '%s/images/logo1.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/logo1.jpg',
    'description'   => __( 'Wheel', 'twentyeleven' )
),
'logo2' => array(
    'url'           => '%s/images/logo2.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/logo2.jpg',
    'description'   => __( 'Shore', 'twentyeleven' )
),
'logo3' => array(
    'url'           => '%s/images/logo3.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/logo3.jpg',
    'description'   => __( 'Trolley', 'twentyeleven' )
)
) );
add_theme_support("custom-header");
```

it works fine until i click on save and publish, sometimes it dont take effect and dont save and sometimes it works, but other options like changing the background image or color of the page works well. thank you!!

Comment: What does your php error log say? (You do have error logging on... right?)

Comment: i dont get an error or something, but i have this in php_error_log:

[03-Sep-2015 01:02:16 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''wheel'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php on line 51

Comment: .. and what's *on* line 51? or just before it... probably a syntax error...

Comment: i think that was a previous error i had fixed because i have cheked and all the code is right, on line 51 i have: 

 'logo3' => array(

thank you very much for the reply! :)

Comment: @ScottMcGready man i fixed it! just removed this part:

"default-image" => "%s/images/main_logo.jpg",

i dont know why but it works now or at least it seems to work for now, anyway thank you so much for the reply! how do i give you points or something?

Comment: Great! Add it as an answer yourself for any future folks with the issue :)